# I need a DAX formula to calculate number of consecutive year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get code DAX formula to get number of consective year a client is with us. There may be multiple entry in a year for the same client (Register number). Then count shall reset if there is a gap between the years. Sample data and expected outcome is attached

[image]

I have modified the formula from this resource: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Calculating-Consecutive-Years-Active/td-p/1670339 but the Formula result is not what i expected:

```
Consecutive Yrs = 
VAR vMaxYear =
    MAX ( 'Data: Policy'[Effective year] )
VAR vThisCustomer =
    MIN ( 'Data: Policy'[Transformed Register number])
VAR vLatestNotDonation =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Data: Policy'[Effective year]),
            ISBLANK (
                CALCULATE (
                    COUNTROWS ( 'Data: Policy' ),
                    'Data: Policy'[Transformed Register number] = vThisCustomer
                )
            )
        ),
        'Data: Policy'[Effective year]
    )
VAR vLatestIfBlank =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( vLatestNotDonation ),
        MINX (
            ALL ( 'Data: Policy'[Effective year] ),
            'Data: Policy'[Effective year]
        ) - 1,
        vLatestNotDonation
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        vMaxYear = 2023,
        vMaxYear - vLatestIfBlank
    )
```

| Effective year | Register number | Formula Outcome | Expected ConsecutiveYears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | AX1234 | 0 | 1 |
| 2018 | AX1234 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020 | AX1234 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020 | AX1234 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021 | AX1234 | 0 | 2 |
| 2022 | AX1234 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023 | AX1234 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023 | AX1234 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023 | AX1234 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023 | AX1234 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023 | AX1234 | 1 | 4 |

Appreciate your assistance. Many thanks

Comment: Please paste your sample data as copiable text and mark your old questions as solved

Comment: thanks David. i have pasted sample data as copiable text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a better way without applying so many transformations and that's why I have labeled my earlier solution as **Solution-2** and labeled the new solution as **Solution-1**.

**Solution-1**

First create a **Measure** as below-

```
check_break_measure = 

var cr_year = min(your_table_name[Effective year])
var cr_reg_number = MIN(your_table_name[Transformed Register number])


var prev_year = CALCULATE(
    max(your_table_name[Effective year]),
    FILTER(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Effective year] < cr_year
            && your_table_name[Transformed Register number] = cr_reg_number
    )
)

return if(ISBLANK(prev_year) || cr_year - prev_year >= 2, 1,0)
```

And then the second **Measure** as below-

```
serial_no = 

var current_row_year = min(your_table_name[Effective year])
var current_row_reg_number = min(your_table_name[Transformed Register number])

var break_year_current_group = 
CALCULATE(
    max(your_table_name[Effective year]),
    FILTER(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Effective year] <= current_row_year
            && your_table_name[check_break_measure] = 1
            && your_table_name[Transformed Register number] == current_row_reg_number
    )
)

var sl = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Effective year]),
    FILTER(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Effective year] <= current_row_year
            && your_table_name[Effective year] >= break_year_current_group
            && your_table_name[Transformed Register number] == current_row_reg_number
    )
)

Return sl
```

**Both above and below solution you will get the same output**

---

**Solution-2**

If you can do some transformation in your table in the power query editor and then create a Measure, you can achieve the requirement.

First, apply these below code to your table's **Advance Editor**-

```
let
    //Existing Steps,
    

    //new steps started from here
    //please edit "your_previous_step_name" properly in the below line with your actual your_previous_step_name

    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"your_previous_step_name",{{"Transformed Register number", Order.Ascending}, {"Effective year", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows1", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Effective year"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Index_", each [Index]+1),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Index_", "Transformed Register number", "Effective year"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Reordered Columns1", {"Index"}, #"Reordered Columns1", {"Index_"}, "Reordered Columns1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Reordered Columns1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Reordered Columns1", {"Transformed Register number", "Effective year"}, {"Reordered Columns1.Cat", "Reordered Columns1.Year"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Reordered Columns1",{{"Reordered Columns1.Cat", "pr_cat"}, {"Reordered Columns1.Year", "pr_year"}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "check_break", each if [Transformed Register number] <> [pr_cat] or [Effective year] - [pr_year] >=2 then 1 else 0),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Index_", "pr_cat", "pr_year"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Considering your sample data, you will have data as below now-

[image]

Now go to the Report designer and create a new **Measure** with this below code-

```
serial_no = 

var current_row_year = min(your_table_name[Effective year])
var current_row_reg_number = min(your_table_name[Transformed Register number])

var break_year_current_group = 
CALCULATE(
    max(your_table_name[Effective year]),
    FILTER(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Effective year] <= current_row_year
            && your_table_name[check_break] = "1"
            && your_table_name[Transformed Register number] == current_row_reg_number
    )
)

var sl = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Effective year]),
    FILTER(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Effective year] <= current_row_year
            && your_table_name[Effective year] >= break_year_current_group
            && your_table_name[Transformed Register number] == current_row_reg_number
    )
)

Return sl
```

Your final data output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Have an upvote although you may be interested in this alternative from Alberto that doesn't require an index. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5VZ6k9kk60

Comment: The index is only required in the Transformation part @DavidBacci. I have added in the visual just to show all records :) I will check the other answer soon.

Comment: Understood. It doesn't require a check_break indicator either and is a pure DAX solution that will respond to dynamically filtered data. See what you think

Comment: Added another approach with out transformation on top of my previous answer and I think this one is better then previous one. You can check @DavidBacci

Comment: Looks good to me and an improvement over the first solution.

Comment: @mkRabbani Thank you. I have adapted Solution 1. Instead of measures I created calculated columns as i will need row level computation.

Comment: Nice to see the Solution Somehow helped :)